What are the "rules" for counting transistors on a chip?
It seems straightforward to count the transistors on a chip, but it's not.
For instance, many logic gates use transistors in parallel to increase the drive current. Are these transistors counted as one or multiple transistors?
To make this concrete, the photo below shows the silicon that implements a two-input NOR gate in the Pentium. This gate has four transistors conceptually, but the physical implementation has eight transistors (numbered). (The PMOS transistors are paralleled in groups of three to provide more drive current.) Thus, there is a factor of two difference for this gate. This is a typical logic gate, not a special driver. The Pentium is said to have 3.1 million transistors, but does Intel count this gate as 4 or 8 transistors? A factor of 2 makes a big difference.

Another issue is ROMs and PLAs.  A ROM may have a transistor for a 0 bit and no transistor for a 1, so the physical transistor count depends on the data stored in the ROM. The photo below shows part of the Pentium's microcode ROM. Note that most of the transistor sites are empty in this region. (Each square is connected to 1 or 2 transistors.)

For ROMs, companies typically use the count of "potential" transistors rather than physical transistors. For instance, Intel describes the 80386 as having 285,000 transistor sites with 181,000 actual transistors. But I haven't found anything discussing how parallel transistors are counted. So my question is: how do companies typically count transistors, especially paralleled ones?

Besides doubling up transistors for reasons; ESD protection structures near I/O pads, test mode support circuitry, and one-time-programmable trim circuits seem like they might also add to the total transistor count. But the question comes back to who is counting transistors and why. Marketing hype is as reliable as process node nomenclature, but maybe there's a mil spec document that defines exactly what is a transistor for purpose of estimating integrated circuit MTBF reliability?

...like possibly MIL-HDBK-217F "Reliability Prediction of Electronic Equipment"

Wether a bit is 0  or 1 in a ROM is irrelevant, since the physical space for a transistor array is still the same. x transistors + y non-implemented transistors + z addressing transistors is still a constant.

There is a military standards document for estimating product reliability of integrated circuits based on complexity: MIL-HDBK-217F "Reliability Prediction of Electronic Equipment"
For purpose of making these MTBF reliability estimates, they have different ways of counting complexity depending on whether the device is TTL or CMOS, and whether it is memory or linear (opamp) or digital logic (gates).
From MMIL-HDBK-217F page 5-1:

...For linear devices not covered by MIL-M-38510 or MIL-I-38535, use
the linear transistor count from the schematic diagram of the device
to determine circuit complexity." For digital devices not covered by
MMIL-M-38510 or MIL-I-38535, use the gate count as determined from the
logic diagram. A J-K or R-S flip flop is equivalent to 6 gates when
used as part of an LSI circuit. .... When a logic diagram is
unavailable, use device transistor count to determine gate count using
the following expressions:
Bipolar: No.Gates = No.Transistors / 3.0
CMOS: No.Gates = No.Transistors / 4.0
Other MOS: No.Gates = No.Transistors / 3.0


Back in the early days 1970's, 1980's a lot of IC technology was marketed as both commercial and military, so engineering would have needed to provide the transistor counts or equivalent information in the datasheets. I suspect that in later years, some amount of marketing hype crept in. Transistor counts advertised on page 1 of the datasheet are a bit more suspect than a transistor count given underneath the die photo, if the datasheet even includes a photo.
For your purposes as a die photo archaeologist, I'd probably stick with the "theoretical" number you mentioned, i.e. the schematic equivalent, even though it may be implemented using more than one transistor in parallel; that seems consistent with how and why these transistor counts would have been used.

FYI: The MIL-HDBK-217F transistor count method stopped being useful for high-density ICs a long time ago. For our custom high transistor count ICs, we performed life testing (at very high temp and voltage) to get reliability numbers.

A count of the number of transistors is useful mostly for marketing purposes. People only care about the function of the chip, not how many transistors are used to make it.
Now if you wanted a measure of "complexity" there are other equally fuzzy measures- things like chip size, lithographic minimum dimension, number of interconnect levels,...

In my experience, in custom design a transistor of W/L = 10 could be built as W=10/L=1 (a single 10/1 gate, or from 5x W=2/L=1 (5 individual 2/1 transistors connected in parallel), or as W=2/L=1, G=5 (One single structure with 5 gate fingers, each 2 long).  Each would be counted as 1 transistor.
@Fred 's comment about device count being a marketing thing is a good one - engineering optimizations are for area, power, not # of devices.
